# Aurelia customAttribute (popover) - bind() behavior not working

Tags: bind, popover, lifecycle, aurelia, custom-attribute

I am loving Aurelia.io, but now I have a simple issue.

### Here is my set-up:

I am trying this tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/extending-html-aurelia-io-way/

I am using Aurelia's navigation-skeleton, release 0.17.0

---

Per the tutorial, I am coding the **popover.js** file, and got this far:

```
bind() {
  // initialize the popover
  $(this.element).popover({ 
    title: this.title,
    placement: this.placement,
    content: this.content,
    trigger: 'hover' });
}
```

Now, my problem is that my bindables --i.e. this.title, this.placement, this.content -- are coming up as null.

My hypothesis is that -- for some reasons -- bind() is executing before these properties are being bounded.

For example, when I run the following code, I get "null".

```
bind() {
    console.log(this.title); //outputs "null"
}
```

The popover works fine if I hard-code the properties:

```
//This works great

bind() {
    $(this.element).popover({
        title: "Some Title",
        placement: "right",
        content: "Stuff I wrote",
        trigger: 'hover'
    });
}
```

So definitely, there is something going on with the bind() behavior.

**Has anyone encountered this problem, and is there a simple solution?**

Here is the rest of my code:

---

This is my file **popover.js**

```
import {customAttribute, bindable, inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import $ from 'bootstrap';
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';

@inject(Element)
@customAttribute('popover')
export class Popover {

    @bindable title;
    @bindable content;
    @bindable placement;

    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    //Lifecycle///////////////////////////////

    bind() {
        $(this.element).popover({
            title: this.title,
            placement: this.placement,
            content: this.content,
            trigger: 'hover'
        });

    }

    //Change Behaviors//////////////////////

    titleChanged(newValue) {
        $(this.element).data('bs.popover').options.title = newValue;
    }

    contentChanged(newValue) {
        $(this.element).data('bs.popover').options.content = newValue;
    }

    placementChanged(newValue) {
        $(this.element).data('bs.popover').options.placement = newValue;
    }

}
```

This is my file **funny.html**:

```
<template>
    <require from="./popover"></require>

    <h1>${greeting}</h1>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" repeat.for="p of posts">
            <img src.bind="p.data.thumbnail" popover="
                placement: 'right',
                title.bind = p.data.title,
                content.bind = p.data.content
            "/>
            <a href="http://reddit.com/${p.data.permalink}">
                ${p.data.title}
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Now... I know what you're thinking. If you compare my code for funny.html against the tutorial's, you will notice that I am using commas -- not semicolons -- for separating the properties of the popover attribute:

```
//I am using commas, not semicolons...
<img src.bind="p.data.thumbnail" popover="
    placement: 'right',
    title.bind = p.data.title,
    content.bind = p.data.content
"/>
```

Hehe, naturally you will want to know why I have done this, so I will tell you why.

Originally, when I used semicolons as the tutorial has prescribed, I got a nasty error:

```
//Using semicolons causes an error...
<img src.bind="p.data.thumbnail" popover="
    placement: 'right';
    title.bind = p.data.title;
    content.bind = p.data.content
"/>

//Causes this nasty error on the Javascript Console:

//ERROR [app-router] TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
//at TemplatingBindingLanguage.inspectAttribute
```

So this is why I have opted to use commas instead of the semicolons, because I did not wish to see this error popping up. (It's possible that my use of commas has caused the issues with bind() behavior not working -- although it's unlikely because I tried binding just one property -- to avoid the use of commas/semicolons -- and the bind() behavior would still not work.)

Could anyone tell me why this error arises, what it means, or how I may move forward?

**ERROR [app-router] TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
at TemplatingBindingLanguage.inspectAttribute**

Thank you very much,

-Andy

Comment: If you don't get an answer set this up in the [aurelia plunker](http://bit.ly/aurelia-plunker) and we can debug it.

Comment: @JeremyDanyow Hey! How are you? Thanks for the advice. I will check that thing out. You made that site?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

HEY -- problem solved.

**Donald Slagle** from the aurelia gitter (https://gitter.im/Aurelia/Discuss) noticed I was using "=" instead of the ":" on the attribute bindings of my **funny.html** file.

Now it works. Thanks